# A simple phonebook using FLTK in c++

Tags: c++, fltk

Hi guys I want to make a phone book in c++ using FLTK as a part of my project. It should have options to add, delete,modify and search the numbers.
Since  I am new to FLTK can some one suggest which widgets should I use and how?
Also I am planning to write the contents of phonebook into a text file whose entries will be retrieved/ written into as and when required. So non graphical code is easy . Can some suggest how do I integrate graphics into this using FLTK?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you first draw a sketch of the user interface in a paper. Like this for instance :

[image]

Then you go here : http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/index.html and find the names of the widgets you need. Optionally, do the Hello World example so that you understand how FLTK is compiled into a C++ program. Some hints : you want a **button** for Add, Modify and Delete, an **input** for the Find and for editing the details of each entry plus a **select browser** for the list of names.